# Facet WP Plugin Display Code for Images Grid with Links

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

I've installed the Facet WP plugin and am trying to squared featured images with post title and link underneath. It has to be in a image grid (I hope I'm using the right jargons) - 3 per row and 4 rows (12 total).

I've set the items to display 12 per page but don't know how to put the php for the display this way.

Would like to use h6 with font size 18, and breaking off to another line after 200px wide. Could someone please help?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'blog-square-sidebar' ); ?>
  </a></p>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title( '<h6>', '</h6>', '</center>' ); ?></a></p>
  <a/></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Could someone please help me add the following in this code:

1. Make the title size 18 and break off to another line after 200px wide.
2. Have three of the images with links and title below in one row. And have four rows in total.

I'd really appreciate it!

Note: blog-square-sidebar is already set to 230 x 230 (in themes.php) which leaves 35 pixels between the images with links (total width of my page is 760 px)

You can see what I have till now at: http://www.scrambledchefs.com/recipe-browser/

Comment: Please show us some code and give some more details on what you have tried, and what your expected output would be, and what you are getting so far. Just saying you don't know how to do the code is too broad a question for StackExchange.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi bodangly. I've added in the code could you kindly take a look? Thank you.